# How do I add select options with eval()?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, html

I have a select like:

```
    ' <select multiple name="nav_selected_categs[]" style="height:200px;" id="nav_selected_categs" class="required-entry select">
         '.eval('$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam(\'id\');
          if($id){
               $navCategories = array(2,7,4,8);
               foreach ($navCategories as $navCategory) {
                   ?><option value="<?php  echo $navCategory;?>"><?php  echo $navCategory;?></option>;<?php
                        }
                   }
          ').'
   </select>'
```

I want to add options to select, and I don't know why but I puts me result above the select multimple input.

(I should mention that the code it is in a string because represents value of `after_element_html` attribute).